# JPA @Jointable does not create column for id

Tags: jpa, join, jboss7.x, unique-constraint

I'm working on JBoss AS 7 using JPA to have a List of Beans in a Entity-Bean like this:

```
@Entity
class section {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private List<Component> components;
    // ...
```

The table to join the two tables gets created, but it does not contain an Id, which leads to JPA creating a unique-constrain on one of the columns (SECTION_ID). Which is not really what I want, because one section can have more than one component. One component can be used in more than one section too.

I already tried

```
@JoinTable(name="SECTION_COMPONENT",    
    joinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name="section_id", unique = false)           
},
inverseJoinColumns =
@JoinColumn(name="component", unique = false)
}
```

I guess JPA needs at least one unique column, so it just adds that to the last column if nothing else is specified. I'd be fine with adding a new column "id" to set up a primary (or unique) key. But I am not sure how to do that.

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 2):

The mapping is not correct: `@ManyToOne` in your case means that you have one component that has many sections:

```
@ManyToOne
private Component component;
```

According to your description, you need an `@ManyToMany` relationship:

```
@ManyToMany
private List<Component> components;
```